# How can I make a .command file that I can share without giving permissions on each computer?

Tags: terminal, applescript, automator

I have a terminal command that I would like to run.

```
    telnet 169.254.216.127 54326
```

Ideally I would like to convert this into a `.command` file and be able to share it with many other mac users *without* them having to give permissions using sudo...

Is this possible? Can I create an extremely simple app that keeps the terminal window open after it has run?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execute permission does also transfer to other computers. If the permissions of the file are lost when you transfer the file, you might create a zip or tar archive for the .command file:

```
$ echo telnet 169.254.216.127 54326 > test.command
$ chmod +x test.command
$ tar -cf test.tar test.command
$
```

You might also save a script like this as an application in AppleScript Editor:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "telnet 169.254.216.127 54326"
    activate
end tell
```